# Is there any other way to get metadata of report except analytics api?

Tags: reporting, analytics-api

In my project, there is a requirement for fetching metadata from report. I have found that salesforce provides analytics api for this. but my question is there ant other way? I am a fresher in salesforce. Please Help.

Comment: Do you want the data or the metadata?

Comment: I want both data and metadata

Answer (score 1):

To get data, you can export reports as excel documents directly from the ui. For metadata, the easiest thing to use would be the force.com ide, ant migration tool, or a similar tool. If you are just starting out, my advice would be look at the existing tools first see what they can do.

If they aren't going to work for what you want to do, the analytics api is certainly good for working with reports. If you just want to export a lot of raw data, the bulk api is nice (The Data Loader is an existing tool you could look at first). If you just want to work with report metadata, there is a metadata api that will allow you to retrieve and deploy metadata.

Comment: We have a requirement to access report metadata and report data through apex class and display result in Visualforce page.

Based on above discussion I think the best approach to access report metadata and report data though apex class would be Analytics API. Please confirm.

Comment: @Kaushal This is probably where you would want to start: [Salesforce1 Reporting API via Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_intro.htm). I believe the Analytics api refers to the REST webservices usually used for accessing report data and metadata in external apps.